# Using PHP to echo MySQL timestamp in a different timezone

Tags: php, mysql

Here's what I'm doing to echo a MySQL timestamp:

```
$order_date = date("m-d-Y g:ia", strtotime($order['order_date']));
echo $order_date;
```

The MySQL timestamp is in UTC by default.  How would I convert that to America/Chicago instead when echoing?  Don't want to change how it's stored in the database.

Comment: See [DateTime Class in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Or you could try [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) which is a wrapper for the DateTime Class with some nice extra stuff

Comment: Or simply [`date_default_timezone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and use `date()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`CONVERT_TZ()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) in the query:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(order_date, "UTC", "America/Chicago") FROM orders;
```

Or do it in PHP with [a `DateTime` object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date = new DateTime("2018-09-10 13:24:52", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
echo $date->format("m-d-Y g:ia");
```

---

<sub><sup>Note the MySQL method requires your server to be [set up to recognize time zone names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html).</sup></sub>

Comment: Might be safer to use `new DateTimeZone("UTC")`

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're correct as usual: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php